# Anyone knows how to prove this equation (using trigonometric identities?)

Tags: trigonometry

Prove: $$\frac {\sin \beta \cos \beta \pm \sin \alpha \cos \alpha}{\cos^2 \beta - \sin^2 \alpha}=\tan(\beta \pm \alpha)$$

For example: $\beta = 3^\circ $ And $\alpha =23^\circ $, both sides of this equation are $0.4877325$ for the $+$ case. 
I also substituted other different values into this equation and they are all equal, but I do not know how to prove it. It's from a book, just said using trigonometric identities, but I googled a lot, still cannot prove it. Anyone can help me to prove it? Thanks!

Comment: Is there any chance you would consider an operation called *cropping the image*?

Comment: Better yet - use [MathJaX](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Do you know the sine and cosine angle sum formulas?

Comment: Any chance that you might make the slightest attempt?

Comment: I googled “trigonometric identities” and found the one you need on the first screenful of text on the [first linked page](http://www.sosmath.com/trig/Trig5/trig5/trig5.html).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion using MathJax, I have corrected it, now it looks more neat! It's my first time using it, sorry for the mess

Comment: Yes, $\sin (\beta+\alpha)=\sin \beta \cos \alpha+ \cos \beta \sin \alpha$, but the numerator of my equation is $\sin \beta \cos \beta+\sin \alpha \cos \alpha$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can done using five standard trig identities: $$(1)\qquad\sin2\theta=2\sin\theta\cos\theta,$$ $$(2\text{a,b})\quad\cos2\theta=2\cos^2\theta-1=1-2\sin^2\theta,$$ $$(3)\quad\sin2\theta+\sin2\phi=2\sin(\theta+\phi)\cos(\theta-\phi),$$ $$(4)\quad\cos2\theta+\cos2\phi=2\cos(\theta+\phi)\cos(\theta-\phi).$$ Then $$\frac {\sin \beta \cos \beta + \sin \alpha \cos \alpha}{\cos^2 \beta - \sin^2 \alpha}$$ $$=\frac{\sin2\beta+\sin2\alpha}{\cos2\beta+\cos2\alpha}\quad(\text{by identities 1 and 2a,b).}$$ Using identities 3 and 4, and cancelling $\cos(\alpha-\beta)$, now gives the required result for the plus sign. The result for the minus sign is obtained by replacing $\alpha$ by $-\alpha$.

Comment: You are amazing! this is surely correct! Thanks very much!!! I will vote you up as soon as I get enough reputation

Comment: @Yas: Even with minimal rep, a questioner can award points by *accepting* an answer. There might be a better answer on its way, so I suggest waiting a while to see what answers are posted before choosing one to accept.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know this, this is my first day on StackExchange, a lot of stuff need to learn. Thanks again for your answer~ :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to start from the identity for the tangent of a sum
$$
\tan(\theta \pm \gamma) = \frac{\tan\theta \pm \tan \gamma}{1\mp \tan\theta \tan \gamma}
$$
then write each $\tan x$ as $\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$ and then multiply the numerator and denominator by $\cos \theta \cos \gamma$ to get the identity you are trying to prove.

Or you can use the sum of angles formulas for sine and cosine
$$\sin (\theta \pm \gamma) = \sin \theta \cos \gamma  \pm \cos \theta \sin \gamma \\
\cos (\theta \pm \gamma) = \cos\theta\cos\gamma \mp \sin\theta\sin\gamma
$$
and combine them to form $\tan(\theta\pm\gamma)$ getting the same result.

Comment: It seems to me that in the answer is not proved the formula from the question. Is it?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But it does not prove it, because the term in my numerator  is $\sin \beta \cos \beta$, not $\sin \beta \cos \alpha$